# Android - Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] Installation failed with the following output: pkg: /data/local/tmp/Package.apk

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I got this error message when trying to build and run on my android device using Unity5. Is it related to google API issue? All libraries required by this project.

```
Installation failed with the following output:
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Package.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
5801 KB/s (19486779 bytes in 3.280s)

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I don't know is it ok my AndroidManifes.xml, so far no issue at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:largeHeap="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="13" android:versionName="1.13" package="com.projecttango.experiments.augmentedreality" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:name="com.projecttango.permissionrequester.RequestManagerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device" android:required="true" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Reference: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity

Comment: <uses-library android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device" android:required="true" />
I think this line is causing problem as this will allow installation on only devices which are project tango enabled.

https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/android-tips

try to remove it so weather it will work but im not sure about weather your app will work as i dont know anything about project tango but that line seems to be the case and your device might not be tango enabled

Comment: noted, i will try it first.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is not Project Tango development kit, you may not run the app successfully.

There are some default libraries in the Tango Device.

For

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device" android:required="true" />
```

Deploying applications using the Project Tango framework to Google Play requires only one additional step to the normal Android distribution process. To make sure your application can only be installed by Project Tango compatible devices, add the following line to your application's manifest file.